# Is there a way to pass props by goBack() in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two pages, page A and page B, in page B there is a this.props.history.goBack() function to go back to page A. I am wondering if there is a way to add props inside goBack() to send to page A ?

Comment: Put up someofyour code.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele  Basically, in my page B, I am using this.props.history.goBack() for a return button to go back to page A, I want to know If there is a way to add props inside this.props.history.goBack() and send to page A?

Answer (score 0):

No. Generally you can not pass props up to the parent. However, there are workarounds.

You can write a function on page A, that updates the state (A's state) with a variable. Then pass that function to page B as a prop. That way you can technically send data from the child to the parent by using A's function to update one of A's state variables that you are passing into B as a prop.

[Some documentation for more light](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```js
// In page A
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = { number: 0 }
}

setNumber = (num) => {
  this.setstate({
    number: num
  })
}

render() {
  return(
    <PageB {...props} setNumber={() => this.setNumber()} />
  )
}

// In page B
// function where you are calling goBack()

yourFunction() {
  this.props.setNumber(56);
  this.props.history.goBack()
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>{this.props.number}</div>
  )
}
```